# How do I check if a column have more than two items and if it have than do the avg() on it in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 4 tables

```
•   user(id, name)
•   item(id, description, category, price)
•   buys(user, item, price)
•   rates(user, item, rating)
```

The user and item from buys and rates are foreign keys.
I can`t figure out how to put a condition to take out the items which have only one rating and do the average only on the ones who have 2 or more ratings.

This is the  question in the  exercises
(For each item that has at least two ratings, find the average rating for the item.)

This is my code.

```
 SELECT count(distinct rating) as rating, avg(rating) as average
    from rates
    where rates.rating is not null
    group by item
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is quite unclear what you have in mind as a result set.

Comment: What I want is to get all the items that have more than 2 ratings from users. If an item has more than 2 ratings I need the average of that ratings. For example.  If a user have rated an item 5  and another user rated the same item 4. then I have to do the average of that item (4+5)/2 .

Comment: 4+5 is not MORE THAN 2 ratings. And what if user has rated more than once.

Comment: what I meant  by 4+ 5 is  that  the first user rated the item with 4 stars and another user rated the same item with 5 stars . So I need the average rating for that item wich is 4+5 divided by the number of ratings which in this case is two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the item is presented in the table more than once with HAVING condition:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT rating) AS rating, AVG(rating) AS average
FROM rates
WHERE rates.rating IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY item
HAVING COUNT(rates.item) >= 2
```

Take a look here: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-having/

Comment: It doesn't bother you that you don't know which item has which rating?

Comment: @Strawberry What do you mean by which rating? the calculation of the average is within the AVG() function